# Can't execute a simple psycopg2 script twice when running from ArcGIS Desktop as a script tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, geoprocessing-service, psycopg2

I'm building a geoprocessing service that queries an SDE database (running on postgres) and returns results. I do a lot of development by calling the script from a toolbox in ArcGIS desktop 10.3.

For some reason when I call the script below in ArcGIS desktop, it executes successfully the first time, then fails every time after that with 'NoneType' object is not callable
on line 12 as I try to iterate over inAllCornerPointsList. If I close ArcMap and call it, it works the first time, then fails.

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', database ='sde', user='sde', password='somepassword')
curs = conn.cursor()

sqlStatement = """SELECT * FROM sde.gly_ula_corners"""

curs.execute(sqlStatement)
inAllCornerPointsList = curs.fetchall()

for cornerPoint in inAllCornerPointsList:
    print cornerPoint

curs.close()
conn.close()

print 'Complete'
```

To further confuse things, if I select * from a different table (sde.countyboundaries), my script executes successfully every time.

The geometry type for sde.gly_ula_corners is shape st_point. The geometry type for sde.countyboundaries is shape st_geometry. This is the only difference that jumps out at me right away-- one is a point fc, and one is a polygon.

Any idea what might be causing this? Is there some weird memory environment at work? Calling the script multiple times from the command line or pythonwin does not fail.

Comment: Uh-oh.  You really ought to go back and rebuild that geodatabase using best practice: The database should not be named 'sde'. No spatial table should ever be loaded as the 'sde' user (it should be reserved for administration; instead, create a login/user/schema to own the data).  Please update the question to specify the geometry storage type -- if it's SDE.ST_GEOMETRY, then geometry column is opaque to the client.  You should also focus on the differences between the working and non-working table(s).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'll talk to our dba about creating a new schema for these tables. I've updated the question to address possible differences between the tables-- do you think this might be causing it?

Comment: Please clarify that the ST_POINT is PostGIS.  And yes, it seems that is the difference.  It's also confusing to focus on Desktop and ArcSDE, since you don't appear to be using them -- This is a straight Python issue, and doesn't pertain to geoprocessing at all.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't have much experience with PostGIS, so apologies if this takes longer than it should. The database is postgres, and does (I believe) have PostGIS installed. How would I confirm  that ST_Point is PostGIS?

Comment: The reason that I tagged this as geoprocessing and Desktop is that I only experience this in Desktop-- I can run this script from the commandline (pure python) successfully each time. It's only when called as a geoprocessing tool in Desktop that I experience these errors.

Comment: Not sure why, but it appears that I was querying sde.gly_ula_corners with unicode strings. If I convert these to string, I'm able to execute the code multiple times in ArcGIS Desktop.

Comment: In the future, please include `psql -E` output for the "\d+ tablename" describe function for the differing tables. "st_point" appears to be the Esri type (PostGIS reports "geometry").  Reporting how the data was created (and if through ArcGIS, with which relevant DBTUNE keyword) will help get a faster answer.

Comment: Looks like the unicode conversion was a red herring-- I'm still experiencing the issue when running the GP script multiple times. This solved it: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99578/arcgis-geoprocessing-none-type-second-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with decimal conversion. I converted my database fields to text based on this answer:

[ArcGIS Geoprocessing "None Type" Second time](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99578/arcgis-geoprocessing-none-type-second-time)

And then re-cast to float in my script. Now it works as expected.